# How do I convert an inductive type into a coinductive type efficiently (without recursion)?

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming, induction, coinduction

```
> {-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor, Rank2Types, ExistentialQuantification #-}
```

Any inductive type is defined like so

```
> newtype Ind f = Ind {flipinduct :: forall r. (f r -> r) -> r}
> induction = flip flipinduct
```

`induction` has type `(f a -> a) -> Ind f -> a`. There is a dual concept to this called coinduction.

```
> data CoInd f = forall r. Coinduction (r -> f r) r
> coinduction = Coinduction
```

`coinduction` has type `(a -> f a) -> a -> CoInd f`. Notice how `induction` and `coinduction` are dual. As an example of inductive and coinductive datatypes, look at this functor.

```
> data StringF rec = Nil | Cons Char rec deriving Functor
```

Without recursion, `Ind StringF` is a finite string and `CoInd StringF` is a finite or infinite string (if we use recursion, they are both finite or infinite or undefined strings). In general, it is possible to convert `Ind f -> CoInd f` for any Functor `f`. For example, we can wrap a functor value around a coinductive type

```
> wrap :: (Functor f) => f (CoInd f) -> CoInd f
> wrap fc = coinduction igo Nothing where
>   --igo :: Maybe (CoInd f) -> f (Maybe (CoInd f))
>   igo Nothing  = fmap Just fc
>   igo (Just (Coinduction step seed)) = fmap (Just . Coinduction step) $ step seed
```

This operation adds an extra operation (pattern matching `Maybe`) for each step. This means it gives `O(n)` overhead.

We can use induction on `Ind f` and `wrap` to get `CoInd f`.

```
> convert :: (Functor f) => Ind f -> CoInd f
> convert = induction wrap
```

This is `O(n^2)`. (Getting the first layer is `O(1)`, but the nth element is `O(n)` due to the nested `Maybe`s, making this `O(n^2)` total.)
Dually, we can define `cowrap`, which takes an inductive type, and reveals its top Functor layer.

```
> cowrap :: (Functor f) => Ind f -> f (Ind f)
> cowrap = induction igo where
>    --igo :: f (f (Ind f)) -> f (Ind f)
>    igo = fmap (\fInd -> Ind $ \fold -> fold $ fmap (`flipinduct` fold) fInd)
```

`induction` is always `O(n)`, so so is `cowrap`.

We can use `coinduction` to produce `CoInd f` from `cowrap` and `Ind f`.

```
> convert' :: (Functor f) => Ind f -> CoInd f
> convert' = coinduction cowrap
```

This is again `O(n)` everytime we get an element, for a total of `O(n^2)`.

---

My question is, without using recursion (directly or indirectly), can we convert `Ind f` to `CoInd f` in `O(n)` time?

I know how to do it with recursion (convert `Ind f` to [`Fix f`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unification-fd/docs/Data-Functor-Fixedpoint.html#t:Fix) and then `Fix f` to `CoInd f` (the initial conversion is `O(n)`, but then each element from `CoInd f` is `O(1)`, making the second conversion `O(n)` total, and `O(n) + O(n) = O(n)`)), but I would like to see if its possible without.

Observe that `convert` and `convert'` never used recursion, directly or indirectly. Nifty, ain't it!

Comment: typo: "induction has type `(f a -> a) -> Ind a -> a`." Should be `Ind f`.

Comment: duals and curry confuse me, but isn't `induction :: (f a -> a) -> (Ind a -> a) ≈ (f a -> a, Ind a) -> a`, so shouldn't it's dual be either `(Ind a -> a) -> (f a -> a)` or `a -> (f a -> a, Ind a)`?

Comment: @rampion the outer -> is in the meta theory. Given any f-algebra `f :: f a -> a`, `cata f` :: Mu f -> a is the unique f-algebra homomorphism from the initial f-algebra (Mu f) to a. This is how you get `(f a -> a) -> Mu f -> a`. `flip` that and you can literally take that as the definition of Mu f! As for ana/coinduction, Given an f-coalgebra (f :: a -> f a), we have `ana f :: a -> Nu f`. So `(a -> f a) -> a -> Nu f`. The arrows that get turned around were 'f' and the `cata f`/`ana f` arrows, not the meta-theoretic ones. When you dualize the def. of monad to make comonad, same thing happens.

Comment: Edward KMETT: Thanks!

Comment: I have the funny feeling that *if* it's possible, it will use something relating to the "double reverse" technique, hiding some sort of seed in a functor. And it may only be possible for some functors, if at all.

Comment: @dfeuer Do you have a link to the "double reverse" technique?

Comment: @PyRulez, I'm being extremely vague. Please don't take it literally. I'm talking about a tail-recursive implementation  of `map` as `map = reverse . map' [] where {map' seed [] = seed; map' seed (x : xs) = map' (x : seed) xs}`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is formally possible:

https://github.com/jyp/ControlledFusion/blob/master/Control/FixPoints.hs

However, the conversion still requires the construction of an intermediate buffer, which can only be done using a loop, at runtime.

The reason underlying this limitation is that a value of the 'inductive' type *responds* to a given order of evaluation (*),  while the a value of the 'co-inductive' type *fixes* an order of evaluation. The only way to make the transition possible without forcing many re-computations is to allocate some kind of intermediate buffer, to memoize intermediate results.

By the way, the conversion from 'co-inductive' to 'inductive' requires no buffer, but requires reifing the evaluation order by using an explicit loop.

BTW, I have studied the underlying concepts in two papers:
1. In Haskell, for effectful streams: https://gist.github.com/jyp/fadd6e8a2a0aa98ae94d
2. In classical linear logic, for arrays and streams. http://lopezjuan.com/limestone/vectorcomp.pdf

(*) That's assuming a strict language. Things change a bit in presence of lazy evaluation, but the concepts and the final answer are the same. There are some comments about lazy evaluation in the source code.

Comment: Can you explain why general recursion (in the form of `Fix` here) is required to construct and deconstruct that buffer?

Comment: @dfeuer: this is simply because haskell *concrete* recursive structures can only be declared using general recursion.

Comment: Is there a dual form of [loop](https://github.com/jyp/ControlledFusion/blob/master/Control/FixPoints.hs#L54-L56)? (I like it because even though it uses general recursion, it does not use recursive types (ironically, this function could not be defined at all in a non-recursive environment, because I know a way to use it to produce `Void`.))

Comment: @PyRulez: as far as I can tell the dual of loop is 'alloc'.